# Python3 - Sum Array of Duplicate Dicts

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have array of dictionary list this

```
[
  {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 1, 'price_unit': 10.25}, 
  {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 10.25}, 
  {'product_id': 13, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 1040.52}
]
```

I want to sum if any ***price_uom_qty and price_unit***  have the same ***product_id***.

`My Expectation`

```
[
  {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 3, 'price_unit': 20.5},  
  {'product_id': 13, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 1040.52}
]
```

Any help will be appreciate?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any code example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial list of dict `l`:

```
l = [
  {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 1, 'price_unit': 10.25}, 
  {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 10.25}, 
  {'product_id': 13, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 1040.52}
]
```

Solution With `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.DataFrame(l).groupby('product_id', as_index =False).sum().to_dict(orient = 'records')
```

Solution without `pandas` via `itertools groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
for g, k in groupby(l, lambda x: x['product_id']):
    k = list(k)
    x = {
        'product_id': g,
        'product_uom_qty': sum(d['product_uom_qty'] for d in k),
        'price_unit': sum(d['price_unit'] for d in k),
    }
    result.append(x)
```

`NOTE`: You may need to sort the dict based on 'product_id' 1st before grouping

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain python solution:

```py
val = [
  {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 1, 'price_unit': 10.25}, 
  {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 10.25}, 
  {'product_id': 13, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 1040.52}
]

#Finding the unique set of `product_id`s
unique_product_ids = set(v['product_id'] for v in val)

#This list will contain the result
final_val = []
for p_id in unique_product_ids:
    #Finding dicts in the original list which have `product_id` as `p_id`
    available_vals = [v for v in val if v['product_id'] == p_id]
    #Making a new dictionary with values as sum
    new_v = dict({"product_id":p_id,
                  "product_uom_qty": sum([v['product_uom_qty'] for v in available_vals]),
                  "price_unit": sum([v['price_unit'] for v in available_vals])}) 
    #Adding the dictionary to the `final_val` list
    final_val.append(new_v)
final_val
```

Outputs:

```
[{'product_id': 13, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 1040.52},
 {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 3, 'price_unit': 20.5}]
```

I saw this problem, and the first thought that came to mind was `pandas`. It can be done with plain python as I showed above, but I think there's no use reinventing the wheel when already there are efficient methods present!

Using `groupby` function in `pandas` -

```py
import pandas as pd
val = [
  {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 1, 'price_unit': 10.25}, 
  {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 10.25}, 
  {'product_id': 13, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 1040.52}
]

val_df = pd.DataFrame(val)

#Grouping by product_id and then summing up quantity and unit
agg_df = val_df.groupby('product_id')[['product_uom_qty','price_unit']].sum()
#Converting back from pandas DataFrame to a python dictionary
back_to_dict = agg_df.reset_index().to_dict(orient='record')
print(back_to_dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'product_id': 13, 'product_uom_qty': 2, 'price_unit': 1040.52},
 {'product_id': 79, 'product_uom_qty': 3, 'price_unit': 20.5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

People always seem to go for needlessly difficult solutions or using functions that take 1000 times longer in massive modules, just for one small need.
Prints from checking the timing on the pandas solution and this pure Python solution:

```
The time it took to run combine_dicts 5.0999999999801204e-06
The time it took to run using_pandas 0.004193899999999973
```

The fastest solution here is just going straight through it.

```
def combine_dicts(lst: list) -> list:
    product_id = 'product_id'
    product_qty = 'product_uom_qty'
    product_price = 'price_unit'
    # First create a dictionary with the id as key.
    res = {}
    for item in lst:
        item_id = item[product_id]
        # If the id is already in the new dictionary then add the values.
        if item_id in res:
            res[item_id][product_qty] += item[product_qty]
            res[item_id][product_price] += item[product_price]
        else:
            res[item_id] = {product_qty: item[product_qty],
                            product_price: item[product_price]}
    # Take the dictionary and return it to a list.
    lst = []
    for item_id in res:
        lst.append({product_id: item_id, product_qty: res[item_id][product_qty],
                    product_price: res[item_id][product_price]})
    return lst
```